# Checkboxes from string stored in mysql

Tags: php

I am working on a system whereby a user is given a choice of 7 checkboxes - each representing a day of the week.

If they tick M,T,W,T,F then I insert 12345 into the database as a string - if they choose W,T,F,S,S I insert 34567 into the database and so on. The insert is all working fine.

When I then retrieve the data from the database I am struggling to show them which days they currently have chosen. I have taken the data from the database and exploded it into individual items and then have a foreach loop but I am not sure what to do with it next:

```
$wdays_array = str_split($wdays);

foreach($wdays_array as $day) {
 // do something here
}
```

Further down I then have HTML code which I use to insert in the first place which I need to change to checked if the value is set when they come back to modify their choices:

```
<ul>
 <li><input type="checkbox" name="wdays[]" value="1"/> <label>Monday</label></li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" name="wdays[]" value="2"/> <label>Tuesday</label></li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" name="wdays[]" value="3"/> <label>Wednesday</label></li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" name="wdays[]" value="4"/> <label>Thursday</label></li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" name="wdays[]" value="5"/> <label>Friday</label></li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" name="wdays[]" value="6"/> <label>Saturday</label></li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" name="wdays[]" value="7"/> <label>Sunday</label></li>
</ul>
```

How do I ensure the correct checkboxes are checked when the user reloads the form based on what is currently in the field in MySQL?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

plenty of ways to do this, I would try

```
<ul>
 <li><input type="checkbox" name="wdays[]" value="1"<?php if(in_array(1, $wdays_array)){echo "checked='checked'";}?>/> <label>Monday</label></li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" name="wdays[]" value="2"<?php if(in_array(2, $wdays_array)){echo "checked='checked'";}?>/> <label>Tuesday</label></li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" name="wdays[]" value="3"<?php if(in_array(3, $wdays_array)){echo "checked='checked'";}?>/> <label>Wednesday</label></li>
....
</ul>
```

check out [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)